# how to solve AttributeError in python and tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display the values in the text boxes, but i'm getting this error:

```
blue.set(B_mean1)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set'
```

and my code is:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
from collections import *
from CBIR import *
from experiment import *
from scipy.spatial import distance
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Example(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent,background="light grey")            
      self.parent = parent        
      self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):    
      self.parent.title("PISE")
      self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def open():
   path=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image File",'.jpg')])
   custName.set(path)
   im = Image.open(path)
   tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
   myvar=Label(root,image = tkimage)
   myvar.image = tkimage
   myvar.pack()
   myvar.place(x = 100, y = 100) 
   graylist1 = list()
   resizelist1 = list()
   eq_graylist1 = list()
   cont_list1 = list()
   ene_list1 = list()
   homo_list1 = list()
   cor_list1 = list()
   B_mean1 = list()
   G_mean1 = list()
   R_mean1 = list()
   dis_list1 = list()

   imge = cv2.imread(path)
   arr = array(imge)
   g_img = cv2.imread(path,0)
   gray_re_img = cv2.resize(g_img,(256,256))
   graylist1.append(gray_re_img)

   equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray_re_img)
   eq_graylist1.append(equ)

   re_img = cv2.resize(imge,(256,256))
   resizelist1.append(re_img)

   blue, green, red = cv2.split(re_img)
   total = re_img.size
   B = sum(blue) / total
   G = sum(green) / total
   R = sum(red) / total
   B_mean1.append(B)
   G_mean1.append(G)
   R_mean1.append(R)

   im = skimage.io.imread(path, as_grey=True)
   im = skimage.img_as_ubyte(im)
   im /= 32
   g = skimage.feature.greycomatrix(im, [1], [0], levels=8, symmetric=False, normed=True)
   cont = skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'contrast')[0][0]
   cont_list1.append(cont)
   ene = skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'energy')[0][0]
   ene_list1.append(ene)
   homo = skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'homogeneity')[0][0]
   homo_list1.append(homo)
   cor = skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'correlation')[0][0]
   cor_list1.append(cor)
   dis = skimage.feature.greycoprops(g, 'dissimilarity')[0][0]
   dis_list1.append(dis)

   feature_matrix_ip = zip( B_mean1 , G_mean1 , R_mean1, cont_list1 , ene_list1 , homo_list1 , cor_list1 , dis_list1)
   blue.set(B_mean1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1105x605+300+300")
app = Example(root)

label = Label(app, text='Python Image Search', fg = 'black',font = 'PoorRichard 24')
label.pack()
label.place(y = 5, x = 0)

img = Image.open('logo.png')
bg_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

label1 = Label(app, image = bg_img)
label1.place(y = 5, x = 1225)

custName = StringVar(None)
yourName = Entry(app, textvariable=custName)
yourName.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
 yourName.update()
yourName.focus_set()
yourName.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20,anchor='n')
yourName.place(y = 60, x = 100, width = 525, height = 25)

blue_label = Label(app,text = 'Blue Mean')
blue_label.place(x = 850,y = 140)
blue = IntVar()
blue_text = Entry(app,textvariable = blue)
blue_text.place(x = 1000,y = 140)

button = Button(app, text='Select an Image',command = open)
button.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1,anchor='ne')
button.place( x = 650, y = 60)

root.mainloop()
```

All I want to know is how to display the values into the textbox. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

Comment: @Julius an example will help me :)

Comment: What is the Text box? in which variable is it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `blue.set(...)`? Are you trying to somehow change the value of `blue`? Or, are you attempting to get the value of `blue`, and make it visible in a widget? If so, which widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley i want to show the blue mean value in the text box. when i tried the above code i got that AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the variable name `blue` for two different things. At one point it's a numpy array and at another it is an `IntVar`. When you call `blue.set(...)`, you are doing that at the point where `blue` references a numpy array, hence the error message `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set'`

Try changing the name of your IntVar to something else, such as `blue_var`, and make sure you change it everywhere.