# how to display the values in Entry in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, numpy, tkinter

I wanted to know how to display the integer and double values in the text box. As I have to calculate mean values of an image, and I want those values to be displayed in the text box in the GUI.

When I tried with my code I got an error:

```
AttributeError: numpy.ndarray object has no attribute set
```

This is because I'm using `.set()` for **ndarray**. But without `.set()` how to send the values to the textbox?

Here's my code snippet:

```
def open():
    path=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image File",'.jpg')])
    blue, green, red = cv2.split(re_img)
    total = re_img.size
    B = sum(blue) / total
    G = sum(green) / total
    R = sum(red) / total
    B_mean1.append(B)
    G_mean1.append(G)
    R_mean1.append(R)

    blue.set(B_mean)

root = Tk()
blue_label = Label(app,text = 'Blue Mean')
blue_label.place(x = 850,y = 140)
blue = IntVar(None)
blue_text = Entry(app,textvariable = blue)
blue_text.place(x = 1000,y = 140)
button = Button(app, text='Select an Image',command = open)
button.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1,anchor='ne')
button.place( x = 650, y = 60)
root.mainloop()
```

I have no idea whether my coding is wrong or not. And these mean values are being stored in list. Any suggestions for this problem?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: `StringVar()` instead of `IntVar()`?

Comment: @shaktimaan Thanks for the suggestion, but no change in the error,it's not displaying the value :(

Comment: kindly refer to [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to solve AttributeError in python and tkinter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839552/how-to-solve-attributeerror-in-python-and-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blue` is a local name in your function, shadowing your global `IntVar` reference `blue`.

Rename one or the other.

Comment: In what way didn't it work? Please do be more specific.

Comment: After renaming the variable in the function,I got this error `NameError: global name 'blue1' is not defined`

Comment: You need to rename **all** references.

Comment: Okay, okay, I got it. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing on numpy.ndarray called "set":

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

Take a good look at this reference and figure out how to apply B_mean to blue.

Comment: There is a global object named `blue` *as well*, and it *does* have a `.set()` method. And there lies the problem, you cannot refer to both the global and the local `blue` names at the same time.